Schema to model user authorization in hierarchical data
I'm trying to add the ability for a user to be authorized with a given role on a contract/site/experiment.

More specifically, I want the ability for a user to have role A on a contract but at the same time role B on a specific site of this same contract and possibly a role C on an experiment of this site.
My first idea was a join table between User and Role with a third column storing the id
of either a contract, site or experiment.
This solution has many problems in my opinion:

I need a row for the contract, each authorized sites and each authorized experiments. It can grow very large very quickly.
No integrity. A non existant contract can be referenced
If I want to know all the sites and experiments of a contract where a user is authorized I have to first query all sites of this contract, then all the experiments of these sites and then find all the rows referencing those ids. It seems a bit hacky.

I feel like this solution could work but I was wondering if there were other way? Maybe some pattern I am not aware of?
PS: I am using MySQL v8

Thanks to @Doug Hills answer I adapted my initial schema and ended up with this schema

I replaced the polymorphic columns with 3 foreign keys (siteId and experimentId are nullable) and I removed the deny/access from role_privilege and added autoGrantAccess to person_role.
autoGrantAccess is a boolean, if true a user is authorized on all child resources, if false the child resources have to be explicitely authorized.
It's a bit weird but is a solution to child resources being added after a user is authorized on the parent resource.
If a user is authorized on all sites of a contract except one it means adding n-1 rows, but in my use case it should not happen very often. And if it does I can still add a deny boolean to person_role.

This might be a good first wet noodle to throw at a wall. The person_role table here is a bit funcky. The contract_id, site_id, and experiment_id are nullable and there should be a check constraint ensuring that exactly one of them is non-null.
With this, you can use a cascading sort of approach. If a fella is working on an experiment but doesn't have any privileges explicitly set for him at that experiment, then the privileges he has at site level would be used. And so on with contract.
Any privileges granted/denied at a lower level would trump settings at a higher level.


Thanks for the answer. I thought about your approach too but let's say a user is authorized on the whole contract and another user add a site and does not want the first user to have access to it. On creating the site I would also have to delete the RoleContract row of the user and insert n-1 rrows for each site.

Denies trump Grants. A guy can have general privileges against a contract, but if he has explicit privileges denied against a site, that trumps (for that site). Your function for determining if something is available for a person will just need to have the right math in it.

With cascading, you don't need privileges against every experiment-role. Think of the privileges at the lower levels as being there to override any privileges at the higher levels. The number of elements that you need is way lower than you're thinking.

I'm probably missing something but it feels like "denies trump grants" bring the same problem but reversed. To model a user authorized on only one site of a contract I'd have to give access to the user to the contract and then deny all the sites except one, which is still n-1 rows.
The only way would be to deny access to the contract but authorize to the site which is not possible. If a user is authorized even on one site the user has access to the contract (but the role for the contract and sites might be different)

Nah, give him privs to the site w/o giving him privs to a contract. Your privilege reckoning will just enforce whatever business rules you eat.

Ok so if I understand correctly, a user authorized on a contract except  for a site would produce 2 person_role rows (1 for contract with a role, 1 row for the denied site with a different role?).
I would also need to create a new role with the specific permissions denied? Do you think I could add the granted/denied row directly in the person_role table?
BTW thanks a lot for taking the time to help me.

Adding is_granted and is_denied to the person_role table seems like a pretty good idea. Proud of you!
That would allow you to grant a role at a site while subtracting it at an experiment. I like it!
So, to keep rows in associations as low as possible, nothing is granted unless it's explicitly granted. Denials are exceptions at lower levels from the grant. That's over simplifying it. And you'll come up with business specific rules that complicate this, but the overall approach, I think, is going to get you there.
